# Перевод произвольных документов в pdf убирая активные элементы

Tags: python, qt, pdf, pyqt5, pyqt

Необходимо перегонять различные офисные документы doc, docx, xlsx и тд в pdf, если есть активные элементы - убирать.

Первая идея которая прозвучала от коллег - прогонять через виртуальный принтер все, любой документ будь то pdf/html/xlsx/doc/open office на выходе получать pdf без активных элементов.

Как это сделать в python или может можно это сделать средствами linux?

Нагуглил пример использования QPrinter:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *

app = QCoreApplication([])
printer = QPrinter()
# размер листа
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
# формат печати
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
# выходной файл
printer.setOutputFileName('test.pdf')
```

Но нужна единая точка входа которая будет этим QPrinter пользоваться получая любой документ. А в примерах документации Qt классы просто вызывают метод print_(printer).

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ИМХО, самая большая проблема в вашем вопросе это "и тд". Интуиция подсказывает, что обобщенного способа отрендерить произвольный документ нет. Если платформа win, то можете посмотреть в сторону [Active Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-index.html)

Comment: как вы нужное форматирование получите, если активные элементы выключить? К примеру, если html report использует javascript, чтобы какую-нибудь табличку, диаграмму нарисовать? Или вы имеете ввиду, что только в результирующем pdf не должно быть активных элементов?

Comment: в результирующем pdf не должно быть активных элементов

Answer (score 0):

Установите LibreOffice или OpenOffice.

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf somefile.txt
```

Понимает почти любой документ. На выходе PDF. Но может поехать верстка, если документ верстался в Microsoft Office.

Для обработки документов через принтер: На Линукс ставится cups-pdf. На Виндовс добавляете новый локальный принтер и ставите вывод в FILE. Драйвер PDF можно найти и скачать.

Comment: да спасибо, как раз нагуглил по поводу cups-pdf. Может у вас есть опыт программирования cups ?

Comment: вообщем нашел такую вещь как pycups